# On click event doesnt work after element dynamically created

Tags: javascript, jquery

I use this for click event of button

```
$(document).on("click", "#feed_show_more_button", function() { 
    var a = $("#feed_show_more_button").attr("name");
    show_more(a);
});
```

Then after button dynamically created i want to use this as a fake click

```
$("#feed_show_more_button").click();
```

but it doesnt work.

EDIT: I realized that show_more function doesnt fired unless it is included the ajax result. How can i make this function sth like global ?

Comment: so where's the code that dynamically created the button?

Comment: php creates the button like this <img id="feed_show_more_button" src="images/show_older.png" style="cursor:pointer" name="time" /> with the ajax request

Comment: [seems to work here](http://jsfiddle.net/RVd9M/1/)

Comment: Just a thought since you are using the "name" attribute as a variable... you don't have multiple buttons with that ID in your page, do you?

Comment: Try to change `var a = $("#feed_show_more_button").attr("name");` to `var a = $(this).attr('name');` in your handler.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of fake call:

```
$("#feed_show_more_button").click();
```

you could simply write:

```
show_more( $("#feed_show_more_button").attr("name") );
```

If `show_more` is accessible(visible on scope) of course.

Comment: soo true, but fiddle showed to me that it actually works. will try

Answer (score 0):

I am suspecting the diagnosis because the console logs "foo my button" when I paste this code into the javascript console (firebug)

```
$(document).on("click", "#feed_show_more_button", function() { 
    var a = $("#feed_show_more_button").attr("name");
    console.log("foo",a)
    //show_more(a);
});

$("body").html("<div name='my button' id='feed_show_more_button' style='border:1px solid red;height:100px;width:100px'></div>");

$("#feed_show_more_button").click()
```

Neat trick btw.